# Error when get data from google Calendar API

Tags: php

This my code.

```
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Calendar;


class GController extends BaseController
{
   public function client()
   {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('/mnt/d/xampp/htdocs/test/client_secret.json');
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
        $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' =>  array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
        $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
        return $client;
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client());
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId);
        return $results->getItems();
    }
}
```

and I get this error.

```
"message": [
    "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"usageLimits\",\n    \"reason\": \"dailyLimitExceededUnreg\",\n    \"message\": \"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.\",\n    \"extendedHelp\": \"https://code.google.com/apis/console\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 403,\n  \"message\": \"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.\"\n }\n}\n"
],
```

What should I do to fix this.?
sorry I am a beginner.

My reference is [googleCalendarAPI](https://github.com/webdevmatics/GoogleCalendarApi)

Comment: `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.` well this is clear ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well solution seems easy to me. You have to authenticate your client and stop using it anonymously.

Your error message says:

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. ***Continued use requires signup.***

It's pretty clear to me why you get this error.